# Having trouble printing to same line

Tags: java, printing, output

I'm trying to write a code where you enter an integer in the console, and then the integer you entered is shown bigger, made up of letters (like ascii art).

So let's say the input is `112`. Then the output will be

```
   #       #     #####  
  ##      ##    #     # 
 # #     # #          # 
   #       #     #####  
   #       #    #       
   #       #    #       
 #####   #####  #######
```

My code will have the same output, just not in the same line :(

It will print one number under the other.. From my code you can see why:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Tester {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String any = input.nextLine();
        String[] sArray = any.split("");

        for(int i=0; i<sArray.length; i++){
            if(sArray[i].equals("1")){
                System.out.println("  #  ");
                System.out.println(" ##  ");
                System.out.println("# #  ");
                System.out.println("  #  ");
                System.out.println("  #  ");
                System.out.println("  #  ");
                System.out.println("#####");
            }
            if(sArray[i].equals("2")){
                System.out.println(" ##### ");
                System.out.println("#     #");
                System.out.println("      #");
                System.out.println(" ##### ");
                System.out.println("#      ");
                System.out.println("#      ");
                System.out.println("#######");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I somehow have to print all at once, not single output with `println` as my code..
Maybe there is an easy way to solve that, preferably without changing my entire code? I can imagine it could be done with a 2d array as well, but not sure. Hints are very welcome too. And this is no homework.

Comment: `println` inserts a new line - `print` doesn't. But you need to print the lines one by one, i.e. change your loop logic.

Comment: @assylias I know but how can this work here? If I replace println with print, the output will look even more horrible :D

Comment: Your current logic is far from the requirements, since you are printing vertically but you want to print horizontally.

Comment: Use StringBuffer and append for each line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `String` or `StringBuilder` to store each line and last print all strings.

```java
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Tester {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String any = input.nextLine();
        String[] sArray = any.split("");
        String str1 = "";
        String str2 = "";
        String str3 = "";
        String str4 = "";
        String str5 = "";
        String str6 = "";
        String str7 = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < sArray.length; i++) {
            if (sArray[i].equals("1")) {
                str1 += "  #  ";
                str2 += " ##  ";
                str3 += "# #  ";
                str4 += "  #  ";
                str5 += "  #  ";
                str6 += "  #  ";
                str7 += "#####";
            }
            if (sArray[i].equals("2")) {
                str1 += " ##### ";
                str2 += "#     #";
                str3 += "      #";
                str4 += " ##### ";
                str5 += "#      ";
                str6 += "#      ";
                str7 += "#######";
            }
        }
        System.out.println(str1);
        System.out.println(str2);
        System.out.println(str3);
        System.out.println(str4);
        System.out.println(str5);
        System.out.println(str6);
        System.out.println(str7);
    }
}
```

Comment: You can replace String with StringBuffer

Comment: StringBuffer is obsolete. You probably meant StringBuilder.

Comment: @assylias in this code i m not thinking for code optimization.. As per my understanding they are beginner optimized code difficult to understand.. मैं मौजूदा कोड में कम से कम परिवर्तन करने की कोशिश करता हूं| (i try to do minimul change in existing code)

Answer (score 3):

Dirty but works:

```
private static final Map<Integer, String[]> art = new HashMap<Integer, String[]>() {{
    put(1, new String[] {
            "   #   ",
            "  ##   ",
            " # #   ",
            "   #   ",
            "   #   ",
            "   #   ",
            " ##### " });
    put(2, new String[] {
            " ##### ",
            "#     #",
            "      #",
            " ##### ",
            "#      ",
            "#      ",
            "#######" });
    }};

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] input = { 1, 1, 2 };
    for (int row = 0; row < 7; row++) {
        for (int num : input) {
            System.out.print(art.get(num)[row] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

I skipped the scanner code and assumed an input of `1 1 2`.

**Output**

```
   #       #     #####  
  ##      ##    #     # 
 # #     # #          # 
   #       #     #####  
   #       #    #       
   #       #    #       
 #####   #####  #######
```

Answer (score 2):

Suggested logic:

- place the strings, line by line, in arrays:

  ```
  private static final String[] ONE = { "  #  ",
                                        " ##  ",
                                        ... };
  ```
- run two nested for loops:

  ```
  for (int i = 0; i < heightOfPrintedDigits; i++) {
    for (String number : sArray) {
      ... //use print here but finish with an empty println("") to insert a new line
    }
  }
  ```

Answer (score 2):

Use string arrays to store the multi-line representation of each number, and then use a map to store all the numbers.  A string number can serve as the key, which would return a string array representation for that string number.

```
final int NUM_HEIGHT = 7;
String any = "1 1 2";
String[] one = new String[] {
    "  #  ",
    " ##  ",
    "# #  ",
    "  #  ",
    "  #  ",
    "  #  ",
    "#####"};
String[] two = new String[] {
    " #####  ",
    "#     # ",
    "      # ",
    " #####  ",
    "#       ",
    "#       ",
    "####### "};
Map<String, String[]> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("1", one);
map.put("2", two);

String[] numbers = any.split("\\s");
for (int i=0; i < NUM_HEIGHT; ++i) {
    StringBuilder line = new StringBuilder();
    for (String number : numbers) {
        line.append(map.get(number)[i]);
        line.append("  ");
    }
    System.out.println(line);
}
```